# Perform anonymous function on an object

Tags: scala, lambda, anonymous-function

This is probably very simple but I'm trying to perform an anonymous function on a list object (not the elements of a list). For example, is it possible to write the following as a single line?

```scala
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = a :+ a.last
```

I'm just trying to make some code a bit more concise/ avoid meaningless val names

I have tried searching online documentation, but without knowing the technical terms for what I'm trying to achieve, I haven't found anything

Comment: `val b = List(1,2,3,3)` is a single line ...

Comment: You probably want `pipe` from https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/package$$chaining$.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define an anonymous function and invoke it immediately:

```
val b = ((a: List[Int]) => a :+ a.last)(List(1, 2, 3))
// val b: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3)
```

However, this still requires the definition of a meaningless parameter name `a`, and is arguably less concise and harder to understand than the original code.

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez noted in the comments, the `pipe` method is an alternative option that allows the type of the `a` parameter to be inferred:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

val b = List(1, 2, 3).pipe(a => a :+ a.last)
```

If the goal is to avoid polluting the local variable namespace, another option is a block expression:

```
val b = {
  val a = List(1,2,3)
  a :+ a.last
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Pipe is just what I was looking for.